# How to recover deleted Windows boot files?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, uefi, windows-10

In case you get confused, ***my main desire is that Windows boots smoothly.I'm open to all suggestions.***

Summary of what I messed up afaik:

Somehow *grub got corrupted*; and i tried to fix it by changing the boot order from **efibootmgr**. I thought, there were unnecessary duplicate *boot files, and i deleted couple of them* (I guess this is where I messed it up).

After that I had to reinstall Ubuntu, but I couldn't boot into Windows anymore.

[image: After Clicking Windows Boot UEFI fbx64.efi inside Grub Loader]

[image: After Clicking Windows Boot Manager]

What I have tried:
 - Made a W10 usb (unetbootin), tried repair but had failed.
 - Tried these via command prompt:

> bootrec /RebuildBcd
>
> bootrec /fixMbr
>
> bootrec /fixboot

- I had restore points but I can't see them via W10 live usb.
- I also made a repair disk by using Windows's own system. But It doesn't appear in boot menu, or the system doesn't see it.It says
  something like that "Press a button when you place a disk".

**Questions**

- Can I solve this issue from Ubuntu?
- Is there package programs like 'boot-repair', which specialized for
  Windows?

*Additional Info:*
I have Ubuntu on my hard drive, and I have Windows 10 on my SSD. I want them to work seperately, if possible. So that I wouldn't deal with grub-windows complications.

Comment: I have seen your error multiple times, but there  is not normally /EFI/Boot/grubx64.efi nor should there be. In /EFI/Boot should just be bootx64.efi which is often a  copy of Windows efi boot file or copy of shimx64.efi.  See IV option: https://askubuntu.com/questions/486752/dual-boot-win-8-ubuntu-loads-only-win/486789#486789

Comment: I have bootx64.efi in my windows recovery disk.Would it be useful? I changed it with the original but didn't seem to work.   I guess rEFInd just adjusts the boot order. I've set it but Windows boot gives the same error.  I can boot into Ubuntu but I cant boot into Windows. Its very frustrating.

Comment: If you have a bootx64.efi in Windows recovery, that will just a copy of the standard Windows boot file  bootmgfw.efi. Its just bootx64.efi is the fallback or hard drive entry. It also is the standard entry to boot external flash drives or hard drives. And the version to boot install media may not be the full version in an install. Post the link to the Create BootInfo summary report. Is part of Boot-Repair:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Info Do not know Windows repair tools for UEFI.